# prestashop $this->l

Tags: php, localization, prestashop

with prestashop 1.4.8, PHP 5.3 I want to do this in a module.

```
$myVar = 'Vincent';
echo $this->l($myVar);
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, and what the 'real' difference with

```
echo $this->l('Vincent')
```

I need to do this becose labels comes from XML files from my own modules configuration system.

any idea ?

Thanks you all.

Comment: @Brice is basically saying there seems to be nothing wrong with your code, are you sure the data you're collecting from the XML file is not `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

Hi,

When you want to translate something in PrestaShop, you have to use the l function.

This :

```php
$fieldToTranslate = $this->l('My Text to translate');  
echo $fieldToTranslate;
```

Is similar to :

```php
echo $this->l('My Text to translate');
```

When using echo, you should see the translated string..depending on the selected language..

If it does not work, then you should check if the l function is available for you module...did you inherit from the right class? etc.

Hope this helps,

Br,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$myVar = 'Vincent';
echo $this->l($myVar, 'your module name');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but here are my 2 cents.

The reason is, that Prestashop expects a literal string. It makes no sense to pass a variable to prestashops translate function. How would the translation module know which translation to use if the word to be translated could be any string possible?

I would guess that this is also the reason why double quoted strings don't work... they could contain variables.